# Ambito de variables en funciones anonimas php

Tags: php, funciones

Estoy viendo las funciones anónimas en php en la documentación oficial. Cuando llego al ejemplo de un carrito no comprendo como como el método llamadaDeRetorno accede a las variables cantidad y producto pues no se las pasa como un argumento y no están instanciadas en ninguna parte.Solo están declaradas en el método añadir.
Según la documentación:

> El ámbito padre de un cierre es la función en la que dicho cierre fue declarado (no necesariamente la función desde la que se llamó). Vea el siguiente ejemplo:

El ejemplo esta en la documentación oficial:

```
 <?php
```

class Carrito {

```
const PRECIO_MANTEQUILLA = 1.00;
const PRECIO_LECHE = 3.00;
const PRECIO_HUEVOS = 6.95;

protected $productos = array();

public function anadir($producto, $cantidad) {
    $this->productos[$producto] = $cantidad; 
}
public function obtenerCantidad($producto) {
    return isset($this->productos[$producto]) ? $this->productos[$producto] : FALSE;
}

public function obtenerTotal($impuesto) {

    $total = 0.00;

    $llamadaDeRetorno = function($cantidad, $producto) use ($impuesto, &$total) {
        echo $cantidad." + ".$producto;
        //echo __CLASS__." ::PRECIO_ ".strtoupper($producto);
        $precioUnidad = constant(__CLASS__ ."::PRECIO_".strtoupper($producto));
       
        $total += ($precioUnidad * $cantidad) * ($impuesto + 1.0);
    };

    array_walk($this->productos, $llamadaDeRetorno);
    return round($total, 2);
}

//fin Carrito
}
$mi_carro = new Carrito;
$mi_carro->anadir('mantequilla', 1);
print $mi_carro->obtenerTotal(0.05) . "\n";
?>
```

Entonces yo entiendo que el ámbito de **llamadaDeRetorno** es la función **obtenerTotal**.
No entiendo como **llamadaDeRetorno** accede a las variables **cantidad, producto** si son los parámetros de otra función.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es un ejemplo interesante:

Basicamente la clase `Carrito` tiene un atributo `$productos` el cual es un array cada vez que tu agregas un producto con el metodo `anadir($producto, $cantidad)` estos se van almacenando en el atriburo `$productos`.

Cuando llamas al metodo  `obtenerTotal($impuesto)` se genera on `objeto(closure)` con la siguiente estructura.

```php
object(Closure)[2]
  public 'static' => 
    array (size=2)
      'impuesto' => int 21
      'total' => float 0
  public 'this' => 
    object(Carrito)[1]
      protected 'productos' => 
        array (size=2)
          'huevos' => int 1
          'leche' => int 1
  public 'parameter' => 
    array (size=2)
      '$cantidad' => string '<required>' (length=10)
      '$producto' => string '<required>' (length=10)
```

Aqui es donde respondo a tu pregunta, la clave esta en esta linea

```
array_walk($this->productos, $llamadaDeRetorno);
```

**array_walk :**  Aplica la función definida por el usuario dada por callback a cada elemento del array dado por array.

Por cada producto que agregas se ejecutra la funcion anonima  la cual calcula y acumula los totales de  `(producto * cantidad) * impuesto`

Pruedes documentarte aqui.

[object(closure)](https://php.net/manual/es/class.closure.php)

[array_walk](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-walk.php)

Espero haber respondido tu pregunta.

Comment: Gracias @WilfredAleman esta muy bien explicado lo comprendí. Me ha gustado como has descrito el objeto CLOUSORE. Podrías indicarme donde puedo conseguir más información de esta clase. Por que la documentación oficial de PHP es muy pobre.

Comment: Aqui tienes un tutorial paso a paso  en Español   https://diego.com.es/funciones-anonimas-y-clausuras-en-php

Comment: Gracias @WilfredoAleman